# Silverlight mouse events stop working if custom cursor used

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, cursor

I have a silverlight application in which I replaced the Mouse Cursor with a csuomt using the following code:

**UserControl: CustomC.xaml**

```
<UserControl...>
    <Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="EGCursor" Visibility="Collapsed"></Image>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl: CustomC.xaml.cs**

```
public void SetSource(string resource)
{
    EGCursor.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(resource, UriKind.Relative));
    EGCursor.Stretch = Stretch.None;
}
    public void MoveTo(Point pt)
{
    EGCursor.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    EGCursor.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pt.X - 13);
    MyCursor.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt.Y - 12);
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SL.MainPage"... Cursor="None">
...
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
MainWindow()
{
CustomC = new CustomC();
CustomC.SetSource("GlowingCur.png");
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CustomC);
}

void MainPage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CustomC.MoveTo(e.GetPosition(null));
}
```

On doing the above for a custom cursor, the click events on my silverlight `MouseLeave`, `MouseClick` etc. all stop working. How do I correct this behavior so that only the mouse cursor is replaced and other events that have been already coded work the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to false on your custom cursor control:

```
CustomC = new CustomC();
SutomC.IsHitTestVisible = false;
CustomC.SetSource("GlowingCur.png");
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CustomC);
```